# How to create custom type hint in python combining list and union

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

For example,

```py
def print_list(my_list: Union[List[int], List[str]]):
    ...
```

Then, `my_list` will be a list of integers or a list of strings, but not a list of mixed elements of integer and string. But I think this is too complicated, so I want to create a new type `UnionList` like this:

```py
UnionList = ...  # I don't know how to define this

def print_list(my_list: UnionList[int, str]):
    ...
```

How should I define `UnionList` to represent the same type as `Union[List[T1], List[T2], ...]`?

Comment: how about `list[int] | list[str]`?

Answer (score 3):

Create a generic alias with `typing.TypeVar` and `typing.Union` (`|` since Python 3.10):

```py
from typing import TypeVar

T1 = TypeVar("T1")
T2 = TypeVar("T2")
UnionList = list[T1] | list[T2]


def print_list(my_list: UnionList[int, str]):
    ...
```

Comment: Nice. Small correction: The `|` as type union is only available for Python `3.10+`. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union).

Comment: Oh, nice catch! I've fixed it.